# Cannot see my total reviews

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

The color on the Review stats (meta) is really bright and I cannot see the number of my reviews:

[image]

But if I select it:

[image]

I use Google Chrome Version 40.0.2214.93 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. It will be on live after our next production build.