# Is [meta] a bit too meta?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, meta, tag-blacklist-request

I have recently noticed on the Meta site there is a tag [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)...

This seems a bit redundant, we are already on the Meta site, so all questions or discussion here will be "meta". There is currently no tag wiki or usage guidance either, so at the very least this information should be filled out. However, my opinion is that having a this tag on meta is akin to having the [sci-fi tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-and-a-fantasy-tag) and [fantasy tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380/blacklist-the-fantasy-tag) on the main site. Should we blacklist [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) on Meta?

There are currently [46 questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) here with the tag.

Comment: Perhaps it's for questions *about* Meta SFF? Regardless, I think it's a default tag because there don't seem to be any questions that use it.

Comment: @Catija For some reason when you tag formatting it link to tags on the main site... there are 46 questions tagged here. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta

Comment: @Skooba [meta-tag: *insert tag here*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

This tag is for questions about Meta.SFF itself - certainly a valid topic of discussion for the meta site (since there isn't a scifi.meta.meta.stackexchange.com). It's not even being used inappropriately - I've checked through the last 30 questions with the tag, and all of them are about the meta site except [one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10559/31394) which was actually migrated here from main.

I've created a tag wiki and excerpt for this tag to explain its purpose and usage.

Comment: scifi.meta.meta.stackexchange.com has a [meta-meta] tag for questions about scifi.meta.meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 8):

No. The [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) is for questions about Meta.SFF itself, and as such is a good tag to have.

For instance, this tag is used for discussions about tags on Meta.SFF ([Do we really need film/TV Show/Franchise tags in meta?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11156/), [What's with all the closure tags?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9536/)), bug reports specific to Meta ([SSL Certificate Still Invalid](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7465/), [Cannot see my total reviews](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6543/)), and policy decisions for Meta itself ([Should we ever close a question as "Primarily Opinion Based" on meta?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/), [Why even accept an answer on Meta?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9928/)). I'd say that this is being used appropriately and nothing needs to be changed.

Comment: I could see thatp possibly being a valid reason, however the tag usage seems at best to be inconsistent. Would you have a suggestion for a tag wiki and usage guideline? That might help this answer.